# Упрощение кода для работы с input radio

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть 4 идентичные разметки блоков, в которых меняются 2 блока в зависимости от выбранного radio.
Как сделать так, что бы код не был большим и при этом изменение одного radio не влияло на соседние блоки. Сейчас, если выбрать, то меняется контент во всех блоках.

Скрипт:

```
$('.model_descr').find('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function(){
    if ($(this).val()=='bb') {     
     $(".bb").show();
     $(".kk").hide();

  } else  {
    $(".kk").show();
    $(".bb").hide();

  }
});
```

Разметка одного блока (повторюсь, их 4)

#### Заголовок

```
     <div class="result-wrapper">
        <img src="images/4b/before.jpg" alt="" class="before" />
    </div>

    <img src="images/4b/after.jpg" alt="" class="after" />

    <div class="drag-cursor"></div>

</div>

<div class="result-item-slider kk">

    <div class="result-wrapper">
        <img src="images/4k/before.jpg" alt="" class="before" />
    </div>

    <img src="images/4k/after.jpg" alt="" class="after" />

    <div class="drag-cursor"></div>

</div>
        <div class="model_descr decr">
            <div class="ultitle">Описание:</div>
            <ul>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="model_descr check-type">
            <div class="ultitle">Вариант исполнения:</div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                  <input checked type="radio" id="s-option-4" name="selector4" value="bb">
                  <label for="s-option-4">ББ</label>

                  <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="radio" id="f-option-4" name="selector4" value="kk">
                  <label for="f-option-4">КК</label>

                  <div class="check"></div>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="model_price bb">
            <div class="ultitle">Цена:</div>
            <span>88 888</span> руб
        </div>

        <div class="model_price kk">
        <div class="ultitle">Цена:</div>

        <span>12 000</span> руб</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Я думаю тут дело в классах

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вам подошло бы вот такое решение, в случае если есть возможность получать родительский элемент в котором будут переключаемые блоки и чекбоксы:

```
$('.model_descr').find('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function () {
  var item = $(this);
  var parent = item.closest('селектор родительского элемента');

  var bb = parent.find('.bb');
  var kk = parent.find('.kk');

    if (item.val() == 'bb') {
        bb.show();
        kk.hide();
    } else {
        kk.show();
        bb.hide();
    }
});
```